# PowerShell script stops working when I turn it into a function

Tags: function, powershell, sccm

I use some PowerShell script to create a SQL statement for adding devices to collections in SCCM 2012.

This is the code I use:

```
$Sites = @("ULH","LVH","MPH","MAH")

$Query = ""

$First = $True

Foreach ($Site in $Sites) {

if ($First -eq $True) {
    $Query +=  "SMS_R_System.Name like '%$Site%'"
    $First = $false
    }
else {
    $Query +=  " or SMS_R_System.Name like '%$Site%'"
    }

}

echo $Query

Add-CMDeviceCollectionQueryMembershipRule -CollectionName "test" -QueryExpression "select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client from SMS_R_System where ($Query) and SMS_R_System.Name like '%IMS%' and SMS_R_System.Name not like '%MAM%'" -RuleName "IMS Servers"
```

This works as expected, however I wish to turn it into a function, so I did this:

```
$Sites = @("ULH","LVH","MPH","MAH")
$Query = ""

function Querybuilder($Sites) {

$First = $True

    Foreach ($Site in $Sites) {

    if ($First -eq $True) {
        $Query +=  "SMS_R_System.Name like '%$Site%'"
        $First = $false
        }
    else {
        $Query +=  " or SMS_R_System.Name like '%$Site%'"
        }

    }

return $Query

}

Querybuilder $Sites

echo $Query

Add-CMDeviceCollectionQueryMembershipRule -CollectionName "test" -QueryExpression "select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client from SMS_R_System where ($Query) and SMS_R_System.Name like '%IMS%' and SMS_R_System.Name not like '%MAM%'" -RuleName "IMS Servers"
```

In both instances of the code the echo of `$Query` is identical, but when I use the function method the final Query rule does not work...

I'm sure its something simple, I just cant figure it out! Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't assign the output from the function call to `$Query`. So just do this:

```
$Query = Querybuilder $Sites
```

---

Also, you can simplify your function:

```
$Sites = @("ULH","LVH","MPH","MAH")

function Get-Query
{
    Param(
        [string[]]$Sites
    )

    ($Sites | ForEach-Object {
        "SMS_R_System.Name like '%{0}%'" -f $_
    }) -join ' or '
}

$Query = Get-Query $Sites
```

Output of `$Query`:

```
SMS_R_System.Name like '%ULH%' or SMS_R_System.Name like '%LVH%' or SMS_R_System.Name like '%MPH%' or SMS_R_System.Name like '%MAH%'
```

Comment: Awww dang it rookie mistake! Cheers for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Martin's answer is better in practice, but alternatively you can assign the scope of your variable to `$script:Query` and your functioned version will work fine. Open your script in the ISE, replace all instances of `$Query` with `$script:Query`, and run it again. I'm betting it works just like the original script.

The issue that you are running into is that of scope. The `$Query` that is being updated in your function is in a child scope, and disappears once the function is completed. For more information please run `Get-Help about_Scopes` in your powershell.